# How to fill in color into irregular shape using CSS?

Tags: css

I have an image that contains an irregular coloured shape, for example:

[image]

In this example the flag is red, however it needs to be customizable so what I need is to just have a contour there and fill it in with custom colors using CSS.

Basically, I need to allow the user to select an rgb color to fill into this contour without filling the whole image. Setting it as the background color of the images' parent div is not acceptable because the color needs to only go inside the contour, not outside.

I've been told it's possible to use filters to resolve this but my search doesn't come up with any examples applicable to this question.

Is there a way to do this using CSS?

EDIT: you can disregard the gradient within the red, we can fill the whole flag in with a solid color to simplify matters.

Comment: Frankly though...use an SVG. You can't color "part" of an actual image.

Comment: CSS clip-paths would be one avenue to investigate. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) Though imho as Paulie_D says, SVGs would be the far the better option.

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. Though obviously I wasn't thinking of actually coloring a part of the image, but an overlay div or something.